# What type of date/time format is this?

Tags: json, charts, highcharts

I'm currently attempting to use HighStock charts on my site. I'll be using a PHP file to generate the data for the chart, my only question is what date/time format does HighStock use? Here's an example file they have on their site: http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json

```
[1107129600000,38.45]
```

Above is a line of data in the json file where `1107129600000` is the date and `38.45` is the stock price. Hopefully someone will know the date/time type. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a UNIX timestamp. It's the number of seconds(or in your case, milliseconds) since January 1 1970. Most programming languages will let you convert this into more natural date/time formats.

Here's a tool to help you convert to see for yourself: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Further reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Be aware, the timestamp in highcharts is in milli seconds, not in secodns.

Comment: Thanks Tai and Oleksi. I thought it was Unix also until I threw the number in and it said it was like January 31000. I'll just have to do some multiplication on my database timestamps. Thanks again.